# Bootstrap Touchspin OnChange event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have the [bootstrap touchspin](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/) input spinner initialized and I want to call a function whenever the button is pressed.

I tried this: 
`$('#spinedit').trigger('touchspin.on.startspin', function () {alert("HI");});`

However, it doesn't do anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to trigger than bind the event `touchspin.on.startspin` to the element. The correct way to bind is

```
$('#spinedit').on('touchspin.on.startspin', function () {alert("HI");});
```

> touchspin.on.startspin  - Triggered when the spinner starts spinning
>   upwards or downwards.

For other events you can see their [docs](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/)(See Triggered events)

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z894t2wn/2/)